# Inside of clothes pop out certain rigged character positions

Tags: rigging

Don't know how to explain this in words so here's a video showing the issue.

https://youtu.be/AjOcXKPOm4Q

Is there any convenient way to paint out the weight of the bones on the skirt so the inside won't be popping out?

The topology of the inside is almost identical to the outside, so I'm not sure what causes the popping of the inside.

Comment: perhaps a Mesh Deform modifier could be the solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA    or here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imhTnlKrTOY

Comment: To me, it looks like the normals are facing the wrong direction...